# learning about the MarkLogic CoRB processing part 2

Tags: windows, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-corb

Im trying to export the data within my MarkLogic database into CSV format using CoRB.
and the Process Query has been giving out `XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected QName_, expecting Exteral_ or ColonEquals_ or Lbrace_`

My XML data (customer1~10.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
  <name>Customer1</name>
  <address>123 Main St</address>
  <company>A Corporation</company>
  <emailAddress>customer1@mail.com</emailAddress>
</customer>
```

My Uri query

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $dir := "/"
let $listDoc := cts:uris((), (), cts:directory-query($dir, "infinity"))

let $count := fn:count($listDoc)
let $URI := ($count, $listDoc)
return $listDoc
```

My Process query

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare variable $URI xs:string external;
let $elementNames := ("name", "address", "company", "emailAddress")
let $doc := cts:search(/*, cts:document-query($URI))
let $textOutput := 
  for $i in $elementNames
    return $doc/*[fn:name() = $i]/text()
return fn:string-join($textOutput, ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `as` when asserting the type of the `$URI` variable:

```
declare variable $URI as xs:string external;
```

You can test and troubleshoot your modules in Query Console. For syntax errors such as this, if you tried to execute it would give you an error message and point to where the problem is:

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected QName_, expecting External_ or ColonEquals_ or Lbrace_
> Stack Trace
> At line 3 column 22:
> `In xdmp:eval("xquery version &quot;1.0-ml&quot;;&#10;&#10;declare variable $UR...", (), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>10042031709667560285</database>...</options>)`
>
> 1. xquery version "1.0-ml";
> 2. 
> 3. declare variable $URI xs:string external;

Also, if you wanted to test your process module, you can assign a single value to the `$URI` to process:

```
declare variable $URI as xs:string external := "/testDoc.xml";
```